# php code for updating records on mysql database

Tags: php

Im really new to php and need some help with coding. I have a mysql database with a table 'users' that contains 4 fields.

'room', 'first name', 'last name', 'weight' is there a way i can create a new record for each person everytime they are weighed?  and be recalled by date at a later time?

any help greatfully received!

Comment: Do you use native PHP or a framework as Symfony, Laravel, ...

Comment: learn at https://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Or, learn literally anywhere else.

Comment: im using native php, im not asking for someone to supply me code just where i should start what sort of method or function

Comment: Even if you use native PHP, you can always install and use Doctrine ORM (detached of Symfony) and just play with Entity and Repository that help you for your CRUD operations and SELECT...

Answer (score 0):

First you have to connect to your database using PDO Object...

```
$myPDO = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $user, $pass");
```

Next you have to create your create query, something like :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO my-table (room, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:room, :firstName, :lastName);
```

You have next to create a statement :

```
$statement = $myPDO->prepare($query);
```

Then bind your datas (becoming from a form, or csv file, ...) in order to execute the full query, something as :

```
$myDatas = [":room" => 102, ":firstName" => "You", ":lastName" => "Your Name"];
```

Finally :

```
$statement->execute($myDatas);
```

You can execute this in a try catch structure to intercept errors and fallback with a log, or whatever you want.